# Adding items of a CSV text file to a listbox in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, text, csv, listbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error switch CVS text file item when selecting listbox item in Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385092/error-switch-cvs-text-file-item-when-selecting-listbox-item-in-visual-basic)

I'm trying to import lines I have in a text file to a list box, but I got this error message:

--Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.--

The information in the text file is like this:

```
       Ball,Krystal,F,1981
       Banks,Robin,F,1988
       Burgher,Hamilton,M,1980
       Early,Brighton,M,1989
       Hedd,MT,M,1960
       Hogg,Ima,F,1953
       Knapp,Anita,F,1970
       Overnout,Roger,M,1968
       Psito,Arnie,M,1962
       Teak,Anne,F,1939
```

And my code is as follows:

```
    Dim names() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Info.txt")
    Dim query = From line In names
                Let data = line.Split(","c)
                Let lName = data(0)
                Let fName = data(1)
                Let gender = data(2)
                Let yOB = CInt(data(3))
                Select lName, fName, gender, yOB
    For Each person In query
        lstLNames.Items.Add(person.lName)
    Next
```

Can someone please let me know what's wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably have a new line in the end of your csv file